# Pull all assets from a specific volume subfolder id

Tags: assets, craft3

Is there a way to pull all assets from a volume subfolder id?

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('pages').type('genealogy').search('pageType:stake') %}
{% for entry in entries.all() %}
    {% if entry.id == x %}
        get all assets from volume subfolder a
    {% elseif entry.id == y %}
        get all assets from volume subfolder b
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Twig

```twig
{% set assets = craft.assets.volumeId(y).folderId(x).all() %}
```

#### PHP

```PHP
$assets = Asset::find()->volumeId(y)->folderId(x)->all();
```

Comment: Live can be so simple! Up and running, thanks